# Questions on RStudio and R cache directories on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Tags: r, caching, rstudio, working-directory

I have a question regards: **RStudio and R cache/working directories**.

RStudio sets up a cache directory in **~/.rstudio-desktop**.

And there is also a R cache directory at **~/R**.

What is the **best way to set the cache directory** for RStudio **to a different location**, by setting environment variables or properties file, or some other way?

Thank you.

Comment: You should really only ask one specific question per post to get the best answers.  Have you checked the RStudio web page?

Comment: Thanks Richard. but, they are based around the same question - the cache / working directory: ~/.rstudio-desktop: how to best create / relocate it. I will keep it shorter next time.